# Symfony2 Highcharts-Bundle with dynamic update

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, highcharts

i am using the Symfony2 Framework and also the Highcharts-Bundle. For the project it will be nessecary to get dynamic updates displaying the charts with most up-to-date values every second/10 seconds (as you can see here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update).

My problem is that I cannot realize this using the Highcharts-Bundle in Symfony2. As you can see here the jquery/js code is different:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    }
}
```

Compared to the jquery/js code the bundle generates:

```
$(function( {
    var datachart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    .......
    })
})
```

I didn't find any way to set an dynamic chart using the symfony bundle from Highcharts. Did I missed something?

**UPDATE:**
As you can see here the graph won't get refreshed.

https://jsfiddle.net/1naoxawr/4/

Comment: Dynamic update is in the chart event load, so it doesn't matter if you have var datachart = new Highcharts.Chart() or $('#container').highcharts()

Comment: Maybe the problem is located in jquery (where I am a newbie). My problem is that the graph won't get refreshed.

https://jsfiddle.net/1naoxawr/4/

Comment: The problem is that you are adding points to the first series with `shift=true`, but you don't have any points to shift. See demo with disabled `shift` param in `addPoint()` method: https://jsfiddle.net/1naoxawr/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pawel Fus is finally got it:

My mistake was

```
var series = this.series[0];
```

but it had to be

```
var series = this.series[1];
```

See also:
http://jsfiddle.net/1naoxawr/18/